GravityForms/GravityFlow capture submission fee, authorize product payment on submit
I'm looking for some ideas on how to implement capturing a submission fee and authorizing the payment for a product price on submit of a single form. Ideally the fee would be included in the product price but I think that's going to be overly complicated so if it needs to just be an add on thats fine.
I'm wondering if I can use multiple stripe/paypal feeds and conditionally authorize/capture the feeds, can approve/reject individual products or product options with GravityFlow workflow steps, or can I use multiple capture steps to capture different payments for different products/options in the form? Or am I looking at needing to use nested/child forms?
Seems to be several potential routes to possibly achieve this but not sure if it is actually possible and I'm wondering if anyone has some experience. Appreciate the help!
